How can I identify which flow a WhatsApp response belongs to if the response does not include a flow ID?
I have multiple WhatsApp flows set up in my account, and I've configured a webhook to receive responses. However, I'm receiving responses from the flows, but they do not include a flow ID. How can I determine which flow each response corresponds to
i tried to look in there docs but found nothing, i was expecting a flow-id included in a flow response.

The flow response does not include a flow ID field. You can include a custom field in your flow payload or an identifier in the flow_token field if needed.

Thank you, @gafi, for your response!
If anyone is still looking for the answer, you can visit the Facebook docs for information on sending a flow to a user. There, you can see where to include the flow_token.
You can put your flow_id in the flow token, and you'll receive the flow_id in the response as flow_token. This way, you can check which flow the response corresponds to.
It works for me!
